# Accessing angular's rootScope from within a directive template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have seen some suggestions on trying to achieve this, but I can't seem to find a direct solution to what I need.

I have certain values stored in arrays and objects in the rootScope in my app, I would like to be able to access these from different directives templates in my project.

Comment: You can simply inject `$rootScope` inside your directive and then access the values. But please don't do that. It's a really bad practice to store data in the `$rootScope`. Use a `service` instead and inject it in the directive.

Comment: Would the service access the rootScope to get the objects and pass them along to my directive?

Comment: Actually yes, but it's again a bad practice. The bad practice is to store stuff in the `$rootScope`. Create a service. When you store your data in the `$rootScope`, instead of doing that, inject the new created service, and store the data within it. Then inside your directive inject that service and access your values. Does it make sense?

Comment: Yes that makes more sense, thank you. I could use the service to store my objects and access them at a later time by injecting it again if I understand what you mean.

Comment: exactly. 100% correct. This makes also everything more testable. If you have simple "constants" to access, instead of creating a service, create directly a `constant` and inject the constant where you need

Comment: Thank you, I had objects such as menu definitions where it is an object with n objects within it so I wasn't sure if I should store it in rootScope or somewhere else to be able to access them from different directives and controllers if needed.

Comment: If they are static values, absolutely a `constant` is the right place. If they are dynamic, a `service` would be a better place. You can call it like `menuService` and put inside all the menu's data and all the operations eventually needed by the menu or related to them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way I could think of would be to use rootScope in your directive and store a reference to the object you need on the directive's own scope. You could then access it like any other item on your directive's scope.

Comment: This seems like a good alternative as well, thanks for the answer.

Comment: Also, the comment above makes a lot sense to not even store it in just the one directive but in a service which I could then use in multiple directives as @quirimmo has suggested.

Comment: Yes a service would be better. I was just trying to give an alternate way of obtaining the objects you needed from rootScope.

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject the `$rootScope` into your directive as following,

```
myApp.directive('testDirective', function($rootScope) {
  template: '<div>Rootscope value for name is '+ $rootScope.name+'</div>'
  //other directive code
});
```

You will be then able to access the `$rootScope` values inside the directive template or even inside the template referenced by `templateUrl`

Comment: Thank you for the answer with sample code. Could you provide an example where there is a templateUrl instead of template where I can't just break a string like that?